# PostgreSQL 9.4 UPSERT workaround with returning value

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have an application with PostgreSQL 9.4.
Since the upsert is a feature of PostgreSQL 9.5, I need a workaround for that.

The task is additionally complicated by the necessity of returning the updated/inserted row.

At first I tried this:

```
    BEGIN;
    DO $$
    DECLARE
        _cursor CONSTANT refcursor := '_cursor';
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            OPEN _cursor FOR 
            UPDATE uac.roles
            SET       parent_id = null, 
                      PRIVILEGES = 'blablabla213', 
                      autoload = 'blablabla2' 
            WHERE     name = 'role_name2' 
            RETURNING *;
            IF FOUND THEN
                EXIT;
            END IF;
            CLOSE _cursor;
            BEGIN
                OPEN _cursor FOR
                INSERT INTO uac.roles
                    (
                        parent_id,
                        name,
                        PRIVILEGES,
                        autoload
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        null,
                        'role_name2',
                        'blablabla214',
                        'blabla21'
                    )
                RETURNING *;
                EXIT;
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN unique_violation THEN
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END
    $$;
    FETCH ALL FROM _cursor;
    COMMIT;
```

But the internal variable "FOUND" will always be false, because the execution of the cursor happens just before the very end of the transaction, so it always gonna insert values.

**UPDATE:**
Is it even possible without functions?

Comment: It's only possible without functions if you retry on conflict.

Comment: @CraigRinger can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yep, saw those, but I am not a fan of functions, so I asked a question hoping for possible solution without functions.

Comment: They also have solutions not using functions. But in either way you will have to catch errors _somewhere_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, but I failed to find a solution which is inside one transaction, returns inserted values and not using functions; this is why I asked the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702291/330315  just add a `returning` clause to the final insert

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nice, thx buddy.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually, if I add a returning clause to the final insert, I still won't be able to get the values that were updated.

Comment: If only one row is affected at most, you could `DECLARE _row uac.roles` and select into `_row` (f.ex. with the syntax `_row := (INSERT/UPDATE ... RETURNING *);`. Then, you could open the cursor portal, like `OPEN _cursor FOR SELECT (_row).*`.